# Find the position of a word in a text file

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a function in python to find a word in a text file, and that it returns me the number of the word of the file (if it is the 3rd for example).

I know there is the `find()` function, but it returns the number of the letter, and not the number of the word.

I searched everywhere on internet, but I found nothing. Can someone help me please?

Cordially

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem. [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say for example:

```
text = "What is your name? My name is foo!"
```

In python, you can split your text using space as a delimiter with `.split` function and then retrieve the index of the word you are looking for using `index`:

```
text.split().index("your")
> 2
```

NB: index starts at 0. So 2 here means it is the third words.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i want to have